# WPF (c#) combobox updating selected displayed item

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

In my application, i have a combobox. It uses as an item, a name(string) and an ID(int)

I have written some code that updates what is being displayed as i change a value of an item.

```
((Item)(joinedFilesCombobox.SelectedItem)).PictureID = 0;
                joinedFilesCombobox.Items.Refresh();
```

With this code, when i click on the dropdown icon of the combobox, my item is correctly updated in the list, but not the current selected item. In order to correctly refresh the current displayed item i just modified, i have to do a little trick :

```
int curr = joinedFilesCombobox.SelectedIndex;
               joinedFilesCombobox.SelectedIndex = curr+1;
               joinedFilesCombobox.SelectedIndex = curr;
```

Doing this updates the view of the currently selected item.

But this solution isn't clean. Is there a cleaner way to do that ?

Comment: Just so I am understanding this right, what you are doing is you have a comboBox, then when you change the selected item in the comboBox the data displayed in a listbox or something like that?

Comment: A combobox is composed of the displayed item and the list that pops down when you click on the right arrow. When i make a modification to an item, its display on the list is updated by the refresh() but if it is the current selected item, its display in the box is not refreshed. Is it clearer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this to work correctly, your `Item` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise `PropertyChanged` event in the setter of `PictureID` property.